# Using Process.Start to clean a solution - devenv.exe keeps .pdb file open

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am cleaning a solution programmatically using:

```
var cleanProcess = Process.Start(@"e:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.sln /clean", _solutionFolder, _solutionName));
cleanProcess.WaitForExit();
```

But this doesn't remove all the files from the bin folder (it does for some solutions but not for others) so afterwards I am trying to delete all the files in the bin folder, but it doesn't work because devenv.exe still has the .pdb file open.

I've tried manually deleting them too, so it's not to do with the deletion code.

I've also tried adding `cleanProcess.Dispose();` afterwards and that makes no difference. I've also tried `cleanProcess.Kill();` but that doesn't work because the process is already closed.

How can I close the file even after the process has been stopped? Or is there another way to make sure `/clean` removes all files?

Comment: The process that you're running that is launching devenv.exe is probably still running and holding onto that pdb file. Also, please don't do this.

Comment: @AllanElder so how do I stop the process running? And what exactly are you referring to by 'this' in 'please don't do this'?

Comment: Am I the only one who curious why would someone need to clean solution from another `C#` application?

Comment: @zephyrdragon it looks like you're trying to clean a C# solution from within an EXE whilst the target, or a target that has a dependency on the target for cleaning, is running. Kinda like taking the wheels off of a moving car. There doesn't seem to be any logical reason why anyone would do this, as Sinatr indicated.

Comment: @Sinatr It's a VS package I'm writing

Comment: @AllanElder The solution I'm trying to clean is not the one that's running the clean - is that what you mean? I don't know why the other solution would be running other than the clean, and that's certainly the only place I'm using devenv.exe that it could have reached.

Comment: In that case; is the solution you're trying to clean open in visual studio? If so, there is likely an cached instance of the exe (you'll see it in task manager as the same name as your app exe, but it will end in .vshost.exe); that could be holding onto one of the PDB files.

Comment: @AllanElder I've tried it with the other solution open and closed. Just ended several msbuilds that were running in task manager, still doesn't work. Strange thing though - I've changed to using msbuild as suggested below and it's still saying the file is open in devenv! What's happening?! D:

Comment: Only other things I can think of is that the file is under source control, and us therefore readonly when you try and clean it, or you have multiple projects outputing to the same folder and its locked when you don't think it is, or you have antivirus that is preventing the deletion. If you shut down all instances of devenv.exe, can you delete the file manually?

Comment: @AllanElder It is in source control, but after the clean when I get all the files in the directory to delete them they all have the readOnly attribute set to false. When the test is not running it's fine, I can delete all the files. I guess it's just a bug or something specific to my program and I'll have to figure it out myself :/

Comment: You never mentioned the test before; does your test project have a dependency on the dll that has the locked pdb? Likely MS Test Manger is locking the file if so.

Comment: @AllanElder The test definitely doesn't use the dll itself until it gets to this point. It reads from the .cs files, and runs the tests which uses the test project's dll.

Comment: No; unless you've implemented something very strange, it will include a reference to the DLL and import the namespace from it. It will not use the .cs source code.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try msbuild instead of devenv in this case:

```
%msbuildpath%/msbuild foo.sln /t:clean
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` (My code is: `Process.Start(@"E:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild", string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.sln /t:clean", _solutionFolder, _solutionName));`)

Comment: @zephyrdragon - That path you specified for MSBuild is for a _folder_ not the MSBuild executable.  Try the following path (adjust as necessary):  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: I don't have a msbuild.exe - I thought the devenv.exe replaced that?

Comment: Wait, sorry, was looking in the visual studio folder. But there was a reason I was using devenv rather than msbuild...